# Help with Rails 3 js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Want to update page after jeditable (using gem "on_the_spot") has been updated.  Below works updating page, but after script runs once fields are no longer updatable with jeditable.

application.js

```
$('.on_the_spot_editing').change(function() {
   $.getScript('edit.js');
});
```

edit.js.erb

```
$("#items .on_the_spot_editing").change();
$("#edit_order_form").html("<%= raw escape_javascript(render('form')) %>");
```

Controller

```
respond_to do |format|  
  format.html  
  format.js if request.xhr?
end
```

field

```
<%= on_the_spot_edit item, :price %>
```

EDIT -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.on_the_spot_editing').data('ok', 'Ok').live('click', function() {
    //  tried $.delay(800).getScript('edit.js');
    $.getScript('edit.js');
  });
});
```

EDIT 2 - If data-ok="Ok" is the html5 mark up, would this be correct to see if user clicked the "Ok" button?

```
$('.on_the_spot_editing').data('ok', 'Ok').live('click', function() {
  setTimeout(getIt, 500);
});

function getIt() {
  $.getScript('edit.js');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remark: I do not quite understand why inside your `edit.js` you need to re-trigger the `change` event? Shouldn't that create a loop? It would if ... a-ha!

Since you re-render the form, you lose all event bindings. You should use [`live` bindings](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Unfortunately `jEditable` does not use `live` binding. Presumably because it didn't exist when jEditable was written, and secondly, I presume because if you are going to use javascript to edit a single field, you would not want to re-render the complete form again.

If you still want to re-render the complete form, and there could be valid cases to do so (code resides on the controller, update counters/states/what not): make sure that inside your `form` view, you also load the `on_the_spot.js` again. That will re-enable the form.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It sure does.  Updated script looking for the "Ok" data attr.  Problem I have is that .getScript gets called before jeditable has submitted to DB so don't see the update till the following edit.  I have tried .delay both in script and in .js, but neither seem to work. Do you know if jeditable has some type of call back I can use to trigger the script or is there something else I could do?